# Walk a list, assign names at locations by coordinates

Tags: r

I'd like to use a list of coordinates I have (like '2,1') below to assign a name to the element in the list at that coordinate.  I know I can assign *values* there using `purrr::pluck()`, but I cannot figure out how to assign a name to the element at that position.

At the end of the example, I use `names()` to set the names at the top level of the list, but I don't have a way to set the more nested list element's names to "C" and "D" using a given index of the location.

Example:

```r
# Here is a nested list that entries that are not named, just numbered
lst <- list(1, list(2, 3))
str(lst)
#> List of 2
#>  $ : num 1
#>  $ :List of 2
#>   ..$ : num 2
#>   ..$ : num 3

# Here is an awkward way to name the list elements:
lst <- list(1, list(2, 3))
names(lst) <- c("A", "B")
names(lst[[2]]) <- c("C", "D")
str(lst)
#> List of 2
#>  $ A: num 1
#>  $ B:List of 2
#>   ..$ C: num 2
#>   ..$ D: num 3

# If I want to name the first element of the second list of the top-level
# list, given the index of that elment as c(2, 1), is there a way
# (function?) that takes a list (lst), an index (c(2, 1)), and a name ("C"),
# and rename that list slot with the given name (to match the above)?
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-25 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: `names(lst[[c(2,2)]]) <- "A"`?

Comment: Elements themselves don't have names, the collection that hold them store names. So you can't change a name given the element itself. Maybe you could give a more representative example of what you need to accomplish in code and an alternative method can be proposed.

Comment: @MrFlick I have updated my question for clarity, hopefully.

Comment: @r2evans Thanks!  As noted by MrFlick, that puts the name on the object at that location itself, it doesn't change the name of the list entry that stores it.  I'm trying to figure out how to use R to distinguish between the name of the list entry and the value at that list entry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `rrapply()` in package `rrapply` has a dedicated option `how = "names"` for the purpose of renaming nested lists. For instance:

```
rrapply::rrapply(lst, f = \(x, .xpos) paste(.xpos, collapse = "."), how = "names")
#> $`1`
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> $`2`
#> $`2`$`2.1`
#> [1] 2
#> 
#> $`2`$`2.2`
#> [1] 3
```

Or,

```
nms <- c("1" = "A", "2" = "B", "2.1" = "C", "2.2" = "D")
rrapply::rrapply(lst, f = \(x, .xpos) nms[[paste(.xpos, collapse = ".")]], how = "names")
#> $A
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> $B
#> $B$C
#> [1] 2
#> 
#> $B$D
#> [1] 3
```

(Disclaimer: I am also the developer of this package).

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, because in fact, I am using `{rrapply}`, which is a fantastic package!  I'm using it to take a complex JSON payload (cast to an R list), and modify it with test data, so I am using all of the tools.  The other question I have, which I'll post as another question or to your github, is how to remove names when the original list had no names (names is NULL).  your melt/unmelt works great even with that, but often I want to remove the numbers that become names when no names was originally present.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer by @joris-c fits the bill exactly, and I won't change it.  Here I will add an answer to a related question.  In `{rrapply}` there is a way to turn a list into a dataframe ("melt") and back to an originally shaped list ("unmelt").  That process works flawlessly as long as all of the list items are named.  If some are not named, but are just positional, the process will take originally unnamed elements and give them a name with a character that is the integer position in the list (see below for an example).

I wanted to have a way to remove those particular names, and I have a solution below.  Note that it relies on the assumption that the original list did NOT have any names that were character versions of integers, as the solution will look for names that can be cast to integers, and if they can, remove them.

```r
#;; Melt and unmelt, remove names that arise from list positions in the original.
library(rrapply)

# Note: second level does not have names, just positions
lst <- list(A=list(list(A1A=2,A1B=3)
                   , list(A2A=2,A2B=3)))
str(lst)
#> List of 1
#>  $ A:List of 2
#>   ..$ :List of 2
#>   .. ..$ A1A: num 2
#>   .. ..$ A1B: num 3
#>   ..$ :List of 2
#>   .. ..$ A2A: num 2
#>   .. ..$ A2B: num 3

# Melting to dataframe
melt_df <-
    rrapply(lst, how="melt")
melt_df
#>   L1 L2  L3 value
#> 1  A  1 A1A     2
#> 2  A  1 A1B     3
#> 3  A  2 A2A     2
#> 4  A  2 A2B     3

# Unmelt back to list, but now the second level has names that are character
# strings of their integer position.  Compare to original list.
unmelt_lst <-
    rrapply(melt_df, how="unmelt")
str(unmelt_lst)
#> List of 1
#>  $ A:List of 2
#>   ..$ 1:List of 2
#>   .. ..$ A1A: num 2
#>   .. ..$ A1B: num 3
#>   ..$ 2:List of 2
#>   .. ..$ A2A: num 2
#>   .. ..$ A2B: num 3

# Here is how we can remove those second level names that were just from their
# positions.  Note: this assumes that there are no other names in this list that
# are pure character versions of an integer.

isParseableInteger <- function(x) {
    # False if null or na
    if (is.null(x) || is.na(x)) return(FALSE)
    
    # Check if they are numeric, return if it is equal to its integer form.
    if (is.numeric(x)) return(x == as.integer(x))
    
    # Cast to integer, check if it is not NA
    !is.na(suppressWarnings(as.integer(x)))
}

rrapply(
    unmelt_lst, 
    condition = \(x, .xname) {isParseableInteger(.xname)},
    f = \(x) {NULL},
    how = "names") |>
    str()
#> List of 1
#>  $ A:List of 2
#>   ..$ :List of 2
#>   .. ..$ A1A: num 2
#>   .. ..$ A1B: num 3
#>   ..$ :List of 2
#>   .. ..$ A2A: num 2
#>   .. ..$ A2B: num 3
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>